# PHP - Nested class with a same name

Tags: php, class

In PHP, is it possible to have a nested class with a same name ? Tried searching a lot for these, but did not found any solution.

Comment: Why would you want/need a *nested* class with the same name?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to do on a simplified example? Maybe we can suggest a different solution.